# Why NLopt couldn't find the global minimum?

Tags: python, nonlinear-optimization, minimization, nlopt

I am using [NLopt](https://nlopt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/NLopt_Algorithms/) (python wrapper) for global optimization of the [Egg holder function](https://www.sfu.ca/~ssurjano/egg.html)(range x_i = [-512, 512].

I am using GN_ORIG_DIRECT gradient free algorithm which is a global optimization algorithm. I found that my optimization stops at a minimum (-935.337) close to the global minimum (valley) mentioned on the Egg holder function page (min=-959.647 for x,y = 512, 404.2319). If I use any random guess (far away or even close to the global minimum), the algorithm settles at -935.337. If I use an initial guess close to the global minimum, but use a local minimum algorithm, then only the algorithm converges to the global minimum value. This shows that the algorithm can find the global minimum. I don't know what is going wrong. Am I missing something?

[image]

Green point(left) in the figure is the global minimum and the red point (right) close to it is the one found after optimization. The dot in the background is the initial guess far away from both.

Can anyone suggest what could be the cause of such a problem? I am not using any constraints.

Thanks for your suggestions!

Edit: I have tried other 1 variable functions and I can find the minimum. I also tried the [Drop-Wave](https://www.sfu.ca/~ssurjano/drop.html) function and the algorithm converged to the right values.

Comment: Global minimization is just not guaranteed (in general; and it's surely a less trivial function). In the docs, there is even a recommendation to use the result of your global-solver as initial-point to some local-solver for solution-polishing.

Comment: [Couenne](https://projects.coin-or.org/Couenne) is a good global MINLP and NLP solver. It solves this problem very quickly. `Couenne finished. Found feasible solution. Best solution:   -9.596407e+02   (10 nodes, 1.297 seconds)`.

Comment: @ErwinKalvelagen Thanks for the reference. At the moment, I am looking at NLopt. I will give Couenne a try in case I switch.